# PHP PDO connecting to SQLITE db

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

So this morning I try to connect to SQLite database using PDO and also create a table. Firstly, I create a file called db.sqlite, and then create my connection and execute a `create table` query, but the `execute` pdo function always returns `false`.

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlite:db.sqlite");
$STH = $pdo->prepare(
'CREATE TABLE "users" (
     "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 
     "full_name" VARCHAR, 
     "description" TEXT, 
     "token" INTEGER);
    ');
 $STH->execute();
```

So what I did next is to remove the `db.sqlite` from the connection and replace with `:memory:` to create a db in memory, which works perfectly.

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlite::memory:");
```

So I am confused, why can I use `:memory:` and not the file, and how do I fix it?

Below is the error I get when I enable exception:
[image]

Comment: `To access a database on disk, append the absolute path to the DSN prefix.` See - **absolute**.

Comment: @u_mulder, the absolute path? like right from the root dir, that doesn't seem so good, considering that my app might be distributed, and people will have different path where they will store the app

Comment: Write a letter to developers then.

Comment: @u_mulder, :) haha, but seriously am stuck

Comment: @RyanVincent, yeah, I have tried that too, I am getting a feel that it is permission issues;

Comment: maybe useful? `$dsn = "sqlite:" . __DIR__ .'/db.sqlite';`. On a separate note: I define a constant for the `home` or top directory of my site., called `APP_HOME_ROOT`. All data can be found in a `data` directory under that root. so I `define('APP_DATA_ROOT,' APP_DATA_ROOT . '/data');`. And, yes - this works on windows as well.

Comment: oops - sould be : `define('APP_DATA_ROOT', APP_HOME_ROOT . '/data')`. whatever - you get the idea? ;-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it will not work is because the file `database.sqlite` was within the `/var/www/` directory, this gives it an automatic `RW-RW-R--` permission, meaning that you will not be able to change the structure of the file, I did two things and it worked, firstly I changed the owner of the www directory.

```
chown -R <your username>:<your username> www/*
```

Then changed the permission of the project directory

```
chmod -R 777 <project>/*
```

and it worked for me